# I'm new at GitHub and always get an error

Tags: git, github

I'm new at GitHub and always get an error.. when sending "git push" out of my shell:
The error:
"master -> master (shallow update not allowed)
error: failed to  push some refs to git@github.com/myuser/myproject.git"

I really don't understand this. I want to push the first time to GitHub. Before I created a repository and ssh-key.

I am using Windows 8.1 and the GitHub Bash shell (git version 1.9.4 msysgit 2).

Comment: Did you `init`iate the repository in GitHub first? If so, did you clone the repo locally?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "initiate the repository in GitHub". I have created the repository and cloned it with "git clone https://github.com/myuser/myproject.git" I even don't know what a shallow clone is. My files aren't online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`t5538-push-shallow.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t5538-push-shallow.sh) shows that this error message shoould only be seen after a `git clone --depth x`.

Try again the sequence:

```
git clone git@github.com/myuser/myproject.git
cd myproject
// edit a file
git add .
git commit -m "First modif"
git push
```